# Is There a Way of Providing asm.js or WebAssembly Code to V8 Turbofan?

Tags: v8, asm.js, webassembly

After looking into the recently announce support for WebAssembly, it occurs to me that it would dramatically increase its utility if there were some way to:

1. Have TurboFan, the successor to [the V8 JIT Crankshaft optimizer](http://jayconrod.com/posts/54/a-tour-of-v8-crankshaft-the-optimizing-compiler) output all the assembly code it generates along with the static type signatures, and execution profile of that generated code.
2. Permit the programmer to provide his own asm.js/WebAssembly code for specific static type signatures that override the optimizer.

Is there some way to do this already?

There is some indication that it may be from the following passage from [this article](http://v8project.blogspot.com/2016/03/experimental-support-for-webassembly.html):

> Under the hood, the WebAssembly implementation in V8 is designed to
>   reuse much of the existing JavaScript virtual machine infrastructure,
>   specifically the TurboFan compiler. A specialized WebAssembly decoder
>   validates modules by checking types, local variable indices, function
>   references, return values, and control flow structure in a single
>   pass. The decoder produces a TurboFan graph which is processed by
>   various optimization passes and finally turned into machine code by
>   the same backend which generates machine code for optimized JavaScript
>   and asm.js. In the next few months, the team will concentrate on
>   improving the startup time of the V8 implementation through compiler
>   tuning, parallelism, and compilation policy improvements.

To expand on the idea for a more general audience:

Typical top-down optimization involves high level programming and then execution profiling to identify which pieces of code require more effort.  This is true whether the optimization is automated code generation or manual coding of optimized code.  In the case of dynamically typed languages you'll frequently want to go beyond just optimizing dynamically-typed algorithms and provide code specialized for specific static types.  This is, in fact, what the V8 JIT optimizer does automatically.  If humans want to manually provide some particularly 'hot' specialized cases, they'd need to inform the automated optimizer, somehow, that they have already done the work so the automated optimizer can incorporate the manually optimized code rather than automatically generating suboptimal code.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean? This sounds more like a feature request for the V8 team than an SO question, but I'm not sure what the request is :-)

Comment: It is a feature request for the V8 team IFF the feature is not already available in V8.  So my question is whether this feature already exists -- as it seems it should.

I'm not sure how to be clearer in what I said.  The technical terms I used are well defined.  Which of them do you have a question about?  `node --v8-options` presents a bewildering array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible, and it's highly unlikely that it ever will be, given that it would probably require piercing all sorts of abstraction barriers within the system. The complexity would be enormous, and the effect on maintainability and security would probably be severe.

The web interface to WebAssembly modules (through the `Wasm` object) provides a clean and simple way to interface between JS and Wasm. In the future, ES6 modules might simplify interop further. It's not obvious what advantage a complicated mechanism like you propose would have over that.

Comment: Obviously it would be necessary to impose restrictions that maintained the abstraction boundaries.  If those restrictions ended up costing a lot of overhead on the coding and/or execution time of the individual methods then there would be no advantage.  The main advantage I sought was the usual one of using high level source as a de facto specification (and execution fallback for unsupported environments) for on-demand (as determined by execution-time profiling) human optimization in a low level language.  This has the advantage of empirically driven low level coding over apriori architecture.

Comment: @user3673, the only suitable such "restriction" is the one we have now. ;) Your use case is still covered: you can incrementally put fast paths into a Wasm module just fine. You just have to invoke them through the export interface, no short cuts. In case you worry about the call overhead: that is something that Turbofan should be able to inline away.

Answer (score 1):

For 1. you can play with the following flags:

- `trace_turbo`: trace generated TurboFan IR
- `trace_turbo_graph`: trace generated TurboFan graphs
- `trace_turbo_cfg_file`: trace turbo cfg graph (for C1 visualizer) to a given file name
- `trace_turbo_types`: trace TurboFan's types
- `trace_turbo_scheduler`: trace TurboFan's scheduler
- `trace_turbo_reduction`: trace TurboFan's various reducers
- `trace_turbo_jt`: trace TurboFan's jump threading
- `trace_turbo_ceq`: trace TurboFan's control equivalence
- `turbo_stats`: print TurboFan statistics

They may change in future versions of V8 and aren't a stable API.

TurboFan is pretty complicated in that it consumes information from the baseline JIT / the interpreter, and may get to that information after deopt. The compiler isn't always a straight pipeline from JS / wasm to assembly. Inlining and a bunch of other things affect what happens.

For 2.: write wasm code or valid asm.js in the first place.

We've discussed performing a bunch of different types of dynamic tracing, caching traces (and allowing injection of traces for testing), but that's probably not something we'd expose considering that there's already a way to give the compiler precise type information!